# Adjust Flutter RangeSlider by moving the whole range at once?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I've been using the new `RangeSlider` now included in Flutter. Works great. I'm looking for a subtle UI adaptation, though I haven't figured out how to do it, or if it's even possible. I'd like to have the user be able to drag and move the range (start and end) by dragging on the active handle between the start and end thumbs.

I'm not finding too many in depth examples online about the full range of features of the `RangeSlider` though, so I'm wondering if anybody's had to do this before.

Or perhaps there's another range slider type plugin that might have that functionality...? Thanks for any leads or ideas.

Comment: can you explain your question a little bit